# Storing a datetime with optional parameters in an elasticsearch index?

Tags: php, datetime, search, elasticsearch, nullable

So, I'm developing an application where I need a search tool that will index photos and documents - but sometimes I won't know the precise month or day that a document originated at, so up until now, I have been storing dates in my MySQL table as a `date` or `datetime` field which allows optional values:

```
2015-03-11 // Valid MySQL date
2015-12-00 // Also a valid MySQL date, but a null day to represent 'it is not known'
2015-00-00 // Another valid MySQL date, with a null date and month to represent 'this document came from the year 2015, but at some unknown point'
```

Now, this actually works quite well, MySQL will still order and sort the dates in an appropriate manner.

However, now I come to building the search tool using Elasticsearch, and it clearly isn't happy with this syntax. Attempting to index a document with a datetime with 'out of range' values (such as `2015-00-00`) results in this response:

```
{
    "error":"MapperParsingException[failed to parse [originated_at]]; nested: MapperParsingException[failed to parse date field [2015-00-00], tried both date format [dateOptionalTime], and timestamp number with locale []]; nested: IllegalFieldValueException[Cannot parse \"2015-00-00\": Value 0 for monthOfYear must be in the range [1,12]]; ",
    "status":400
}
```

For obvious reasons. However, optional dates are a requirement and I need my chosen solution to allow this.

**What is the best way to get Elasticsearch to allow me to store optional date properties and still be able to order and search by dates?**

Answer (score 1):

In your mapping, you can declare your date field [with several different formats](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-date-format.html?q=date%20format#date-math) separated with `||`, like this:

```
{
    "date_field": {
        "type": "date",
        "format": "yyyy||yyyy-MM||yyyy-MM-dd"
    }
}
```

As a result, you'll be able to store any of the following dates:

- 2015 (i.e. `yyyy`)
- 2015-12 (i.e. `yyyy-MM`)
- 2015-12-01 (i.e. `yyyy-MM-dd`)

Try it out.

Comment: Where should I be storing this then? If I only need the mapping declaration to run once, how can I manage that instead of running it every time I need to index an object? Where would put this in your application?

Comment: You simply use that field declaration in your mapping and PUT the mapping only once, before starting to index your data. No need to put the mapping everytime.

Comment: Val, that makes sense, but I can't think of a location in my app that is called only once... would I have to query whether the index exists and if not, then add the mapping?

Comment: Then I'd suggest using [index templates](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-templates.html), i.e. you create the template with the proper mapping and then the index will be created with the proper mappings whenever the first document of the given type is sent to ES.

Comment: haven't had time yet, busy at work and uni - however this is the next thing on my todo list :)

Answer (score 1):

Setup a mapping:

```
{
    "yourIndex": {
        "properties": {
            "date": {
                "type": "date",
                "format": "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Also, look [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-date-format.html) - Elasticsearch mapping date format.

Comment: Where should I be storing this then? If I only need the mapping declaration to run once, how can I manage that instead of running it every time I need to index an object? Where would put this in your application?

Comment: I understand, it's just where to to place the mapping in my application, because otherwise if I put it in my `indexObject` function the mapping will be called *everytime* I index an object; but ideally a mapping is a "run once" scenario that only needs to called when I create my index (aka on my app's first run).